# Import CSV file and make each column its own list

Tags: python, csv

I have a csv file that contains data like this with a lot of rows:

```
2017, UNC (1), Gonzaga (1), Oregon (3), South Carolina (7)
2016, Villanova, (2), UNC (1), Oklahoma (2), Syracuse (10)
```

I am trying to import the file and make each column into its own list in the easiest way possible in python.

Comment: Sharing your research helps everyone. Tell us what you've tried and why it didn’t meet your needs. This demonstrates that you’ve taken the time to try to help yourself, it saves us from reiterating obvious answers, and most of all it helps you get a more specific and relevant answer! See also: [ask]

Answer (score 0):

This will give you a list of columns, each column being a list of items.

```
import pandas as pd

def get_columns(csv_file):
    df = pd.read_csv(your.csv)

    columns = []
    for column in df:
        columns += column
    return columns
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the built in `csv` module standard with every python installation.

```
import csv
header1 = []
header2 = []
# so on
with open('file.csv') as csvfile:
    reader = csv.DictReader(csvfile, fieldnames=['header1', 'header2', 'header3', 'header4', 'header5'])
    for row in reader:
        header1.append(row['header1'])
        header2.append(row['header2'])
        # so on
```